# NumberFormat does not display currency code

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to format the value a [Text](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.10/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Text/samples) control as currency using 
[sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.10/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.html). But while the number is formatted the currency symbol is not being displayed.

```
var value = 1000000;
var fmtOptions = {
  currencyCode: true,
  showMeasure: true,
  maxFractionDigits: 1
};

var locale = new sap.ui.core.Locale("en-US");
var currencyFormat = sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(fmtOptions, locale)
currencyFormat.format(value)
```

The return value was:

> "1,000,000.00"

- How can I display "$" in front of the number?
- Also, Is there a way I can pass the currency code I want to Display e.g. 
  '**INR**'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use format function second parameter like this:

```
currencyFormat.format(value,"TRY")
```

May be you plan making your own locale like en-us, you need to use currencyCode and currencyContext params for formatoptions.

Comment: Thanks. Works great

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sap.ui.unified.Currency](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.unified.Currency/samples) control if you just display currencies.

Comment: Thanks. But I was more looking for a solution like @mkysoft